# Spring Batch to Fetch next chunk records from sql

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

Spring Batch application using JdbcCursorItemReader trying to fetch huge records from a table, Lets suppose 100K records in table and fetching 100 records in every batch chunk but issue is it keep returning same first 100 rows records in every next set of chunk.
**Query**: select * from table fetch next 100 rows only.

```
    @Bean
public Step step1() {
    return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").chunk(100).reader(itemReader()).processor(itemProcessor()).writer(itemWriter()).build();
}

@Bean
public Job myJob() {
       return jobBuilderFactory.get("My-First-Job").start(step1()).build();
}

    @Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<Object> itemReader() {
      JdbcCursorItemReader<Object> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
      reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
      reader.setSql("select * from <table> fetch next 100 rows only");
      reader.setRowMapper(new ObjectRowMapper());
      return reader;
   }
```

Here ObjectRowMapper mapping the fields which I need to fetch, Here If you can see in reader() method **reader.setSql("select * from  fetch next 100 rows only");** this line I am expecting return next 100 set of records from table which not happening and same 100 rows returning

Expecting for each time job is running getting next set of records.

Comment: Hello, you don't need to put the limit in the query. It will be handled by Spring Batch with the chunk(100). You have it already. Just use "select * from your_table" as query.

Comment: You are using a cursor which doesn't require a limit. Specify a chunk size and you will only have that number of records being read. One thing to take into consideration is that you might want to increase your jdbc fetchsize to limit the number of network roundtrips. The default is 10.